# Extending Kotlin class by Java requires me to reimplement already implemented method

Tags: java, kotlin

The simplest code to demonstrate the issue is this:

Main interface in Kotlin:

```
interface Base <T : Any> {
  fun go(field: T)
}
```

Abstract class implementing it and the method:

```
abstract class Impl : Base<Int> {
  override fun go(field: Int) {}
}
```

Java class:

```
public class JavaImpl extends Impl {
}
```

It should work, but it doesn't. The error is

> Class 'JavaImpl' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'go(T)' in 'Base'

If the JavaImpl class was in Kotlin, it would work. Also if the `T` was cast to `String` or `Integer` or any object, it would work too. But not with Int.

Is there any clever solution apart from using Integer and suppressing hundreds of warnings in Kotlin subclasses?

Update: created the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33895?project=kt).

Comment: ok... this seems a weird problem... maybe also a bug... I think it has to do with `Int` being translated to `int` in Java, but when you deal with generics in Java, you need to use `Integer`-type instead... if you instead would have the following function in place in `Impl`-class: `fun go(field : Int?)` it would not force you to implement that function in the java class... However, then you would have to implement it in any Kotlin class as there you didn't yet implement the `fun go(field : T)` then...

Comment: Indeed. If `T` was cast to `Int?` then it doesn't require me to reimplement the method. Unfortunately, that's not an option for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the byte code we can see, that the `Impl`-class basically has produced the following function:

```
public go(I)V
```

where the parameter is a primitive integer. Also a synthetic bridge-function (`go(Object)`) is generated, which however would also be generated on the Java-side for such generic functions.

On the Java side however it doesn't suffice to have something like `public void go(int field)` in place. Now we need that `go(Integer field)`-function, which isn't present.
For me that sound's like an interop-problem that should probably be reported and linked back here again. Actually having had some time to investigate, there seem to be some issues already: [KT-17159](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17159) and [KT-30419](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30419), but also [KT-5128](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5128) seem to relate to this problem. The kotlin compiler knows how to deal with this and doesn't need any further information about it in the class-file (i.e. the implementing Kotlin class knows, that it doesn't need to implement something like `fun go(field : Int?)`). For the Java-side such counterpart does not exist. I wonder whether this could even be fixed nicely with the compiler/byte-code or whether this will remain a specific interop-problem.

Some workarounds to deal with that problem (in case this is deliberate and not a real problem):

1. Add an additional function as follows to `Impl`:

   ```
   fun go(field : Int?) = go(field ?: error("Actually the given field should never be null"))
   // or simply:
   fun go(field : Int?) = go(field!!)
   ```

   That way you would not need to implement it. However then you would also expose that nullable function to the Kotlin side, which you probably don't want.
2. For that specific purpose it may seem more convenient to do it the other way around:
   declare the class and the interface in Java and use it on the Kotlin side. That way you could still declare something like

   ```
   abstract class KotlinClass : JavaInterface<Int> {
     override fun go(field : Int) { // an IDE might suggest you to use Int? here...
       // ...
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Meanwhile I had a bit more time to look at existing issues... it seems there are quite some issues that directly or indirectly relate to that problem: [KT-17159](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17159), [KT-30419](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30419) ... but also others that have a problem with `T` as return value, where the overridden function is `Unit` in Kotlin ([KT-5128](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5128))

Answer (score 2):

You can use `javap` to analyze the problem, showing members of compiled interface and classes.

*javap Base*

```
public interface Base<T> {
  public abstract void go(T);
}
```

*javap Impl*

```
public abstract class Impl implements Base<java.lang.Integer> {
  public void go(int);
  public void go(java.lang.Object);
  public Impl();
}
```

So, the problem is exactly that pointed out by @Roland: in order to satisfay the contract requested by the `Base` interface, the Java compiler needs a `public void go(java.lang.Integer)` method but the method generated by Kotlin compiler has `int` as parameter.

If you implement the interface in Java, with something like

```
class JI implements Base<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void go(@NotNull Integer field) {

    }
}
```

you can analyze its compiled version with `javap` obtaining

*javap JI*

```
class JI implements Base<java.lang.Integer> {
  org.amicofragile.learning.kt.JI();
  public void go(java.lang.Integer);
  public void go(java.lang.Object);
}
```

So, if you plan to use Kotlin class `Impl` as superclass of Java classes, the solution is simply to use `<Integer>`, not `<Int>`, as type parameter: `Int` is a Kotlin class, translated to `int` by the compiler; `Integer` is the Java class you usually use in Java code.

Changing your example to

```
abstract class Impl : Base<Integer> {
    override fun go(field: Integer) {}
}

public class JavaImpl extends Impl {
}
```

the `JavaImpl` Java class compiles without errors.

Comment: However, if you use this approach, the compiler will give you warnings similar to the following: "This class shouldn't be used in Kotlin. Use kotlin.Int instead."